# How to do something after Redux state changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I want to run `takePic()` function after Redux state applied. Assuming like below code:

```
this.props.setCameraState({
    foo: bar,
    foo2: bar
}).then(() => takePic());
```

I am doing it on local state function like below:

```
this.setState({
    foo: bar,
    foo2: bar,
}, async () => takePic());
```

But I can't figure out how to do it on Redux.

Comment: What you can do , is have a variable which keeps track, like what you do with a loader. As soon as the action is dispatched you set loader to true and and when its fetched you can set to false, and upon false you can trigger a function

Comment: I considered that approach. But is there a better way?

Comment: umm, i have to check too, im upvoting question toactually get the answer

Comment: Kindly upvote the answers you found helpful. :)

Comment: UtkarshPramodGupta Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `useEffect` to check the updated global state, and do the side effect, which in your case is calling `takePic()`.

So, assuming that your redux is `connect`ed to your component:

```
const MyComponent = ({ foo, foo2 }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    takePic();
  }, [foo, bar]);
};
```

Comment: does not work in react native

Answer (score -1):

You can create an async action as

```
export const setCameraState = () => async (dispatch) => {
    // Write your action logic here
};
```

And then while calling do

```
this.props.setCameraState({
    foo: bar,
    foo2: bar
}).then(() => takePic());
```

Or

```
await this.props.setCameraState({
    foo: bar,
    foo2: bar
});

takePic();
```

Other way you can try using `componentDidUpdate` hook

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.foo !== this.props.foo || prevProps.foo2 !== this.props.foo2) {
        takePic();
    }
}
```